# AI Platform Training Job exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform

My Tensorflow training job is exiting with a non-zero status of 1 and is not giving any helpful error messages. The traceback looks like it's hidden [...] and the link provided is similar. Here's what the logs are outputting:

[image]

I have checked the service account which has a role as **Cloud ML Service Agent** which has permissions for **logging.logEntries.create**. The description of the Cloud ML Service agent also states:

> Cloud ML service agent can act as log writer, Cloud Storage admin, Artifact Registry Reader, BigQuery writer, and service account access token creator.

So i'm assuming that it has permissions to write logs to the logger... My question is how do i troubleshoot why my job is failing with this?

Comment: Can you send your job id to cloudml-feedback@google.com please? Seems like somehow the stack trace was missing.

Comment: Email sent, thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This could be your training vm instance doesn't have enough permission to write logs.Get service account name of the VM,Go to IAM roles and assign `Log writer` role to the service account.